# Store doubles in a stack and get the resut

Tags: assembly, stack, double, mips

I have to do the following thing in assembly MIPS. I m asking the user to give me a number, let's say N. And afterwards the user gives me N values (single precision numbers) which i have to convert to doubles and calculate the total sum. But the calculation has to be done through a procedure that everytime gets 2 doubles as arguments and returns the sum.So for every value the user gives me, I call the procedure and the 2 arguments will be the current value and the previous(sum).I do this for all N values.
The total sum is in register $f2. After jr $ra i add $f0 to the previous value of $f2 and the loop starts again.
This is my procedure

```
addition:
      addi $sp, $sp, -16

     sdc1  $f2, 8($sp)
     sdc1 $f4, 0($sp)

     add.d $f0, $f2, $f4


     ldc1 $f4, 0($sp)
     ldc1 $f2, 8($sp)

     addi $sp, $sp, 16
jr $ra
```

Every time i assemple i get the message: Runtime exception at 0x004000b0: address not aligned on doubleword boundary 0x7fffefdc

I m willing to post more of my code if the problem cannot be seen here.

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Even though at first glance you are using aligned offsets correctly, that doesn't do you much good if `$sp` itself is not 8 byte aligned. You can make sure it is aligned or use unaligned accesses.

Note that `sdc1` writes to memory, and `ldc1` loads from memory. As such I don't see any point in your code saving `$f2` and `$f4` to the stack, and the restoring them, especially since they have not been changed.

It's also unclear what calling convention you try to use.

Update: Using the standard conventions of passing double arguments in `$f12` and `$f14`, and returning in `$f0`, the code could look like this:

```
.globl main
main:
    li $v0, 5              # read_int
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0          # $s0 is the counter
    sub.d $f20, $f20, $f20 # zero $f20, the sum
    blez $s0, done
loop:
    li $v0, 6              # read_float
    syscall
    cvt.d.s $f12, $f0      # convert read number to double, pass as first arg
    mov.d $f14, $f20       # sum as second arg
    jal addition           # add them
    mov.d $f20, $f0        # update sum
    addiu $s0, $s0, -1     # decrement counter
    bgtz $s0, loop         # repeat
done:
    mov.d $f12, $f20       # sum as argument
    li $v0, 3              # print_double
    syscall
    li $v0, 10             # exit
    syscall

addition:
    add.d $f0, $f12, $f14  # result = arg1 + arg2
    jr $ra
```

Comment: here is what i do at the end of each loop:   cvt.d.s $f6, $f4
    
     jal addition
     add.d $f2, $f2, $f0
    
     addi $t1, $t1, 1
     j Loop     also how can I make $sp 8-byte aligned? And why do i not need to save and load f registers?

Comment: If you have the addition after your procedure then it makes no sense whatsoever to have your procedure. You should only add in the procedure. Why would you need to save and load the registers, especially if they are unchanged?

Comment: It is part of homework project. Needs to be done this way. It says to use the following procedure written in C as following: double addition(double a, double b)
{
double result;
result = a + b;
return result;
}

Comment: Yes, and that does not conflict with what I said. It doesn't say anywhere to save/restore the f registers, or to use another addition afterwards.

Comment: Τhen maybe I didn't understand what  you're saying Mr.Jester. What is your suggestion for my problem?